# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value, UITableViewCell, cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: swift, ios8, uitableview

I am debugging this error since 4 hours now ...

```
 print(iP)
 let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(iP) as! CINametitleTableViewCell
 self.contact.nametitle = Conv().strNothingTostrNull(cell.nametitleTF.text!)
```

this lines causes this output:

```
<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0} 
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

The error happens in the middle code line.

What can be the mistake?

Comment: The documentation says cellForRowAtINdexPath() returns: "An object representing a cell of the table, or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range."

Comment: yeah and in my issue it probably returns nil, thats the error? But the cell and the indexPath both exist in the table @TomPelaia

Comment: Add more code. First of all method where you have code from question. And `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0):

The cell is not visible so It will return null, you have to check null before process it

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(iP) as? CINametitleTableViewCell {    
    self.contact.nametitle = Conv().strNothingTostrNull(cell.nametitleTF.text!) 
}
```